# Row counts trouble in excel 2007 VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My this macro has been working perfect, but lately it missed one count 3 times, but still work fine except for that 3 times. I used Countif to count in that excel contents, still miss one number. I couldn't see anything different with that same value, why it missed that one. Here's the codes.

```
Dim DP1_total As Integer


 Range("H1").Sort Key1:=Range("H2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
 FinalRowH = Range("H1048576").End(xlUp).Row

  DP1_total = 0
  For i = 2 To FinalRowH
    If Range("H" & i).Value = "DP1" Then
      DP1_total = DP1_total + 1
    End If
  Next i

  If DP1_total > 0 Then
    MsgBox (DP1_total)
  End If
```

Comment: I don't know how to post the codes.

Comment: Just paste them in at the bottom of your post.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, had to put it on hold. I just got the codes posted, took me 2 days to figure it out. maybe my codes were too long so I shortened it.

Comment: I don't know if I can attach the worksheets of correct one and wrong one here.

Comment: Is there any active filter on the spreadsheet?

Comment: @n8.There's no any filter. thx

Comment: Thank you, I will try these two ways. Try another way to sort. Because this is only part of the codes. I need the counts to copy the right number of "DP1", "DP2"..., then paste them to each individual sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received no error with the code below. I got rid of your FinalRowH variable and simply set the loop end equal to the .end(xlup). Another improvement would be to create a variant to loop through each cell and find the value.

```
Dim DP1_total As Integer
Dim FinalRowH As Range
Dim i As Integer
Range("H1").Sort Key1:=Range("H2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

  DP1_total = 0
  For i = 2 To Range("$H$1048567").End(xlUp).Row
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("H" & i).Value = "DP1" Then
      DP1_total = DP1_total + 1
    End If
  Next i

  If DP1_total > 0 Then
    MsgBox (DP1_total)
  End If
```

Comment: thank you all, I found the problem. There's space behind the word.